# make buttons visible based on a condition

Tags: c#, button, visibility

I'm a newbie intern trying to "fix" the c# code behind for an in-house form. the code populates a couple data grids with date from our database.

There are a couple export buttons that i want to make invisible if one of the grids comes back with no rows (which will happen sometimes as it should).

When you click the go button to populate the grid, the buttons should become invisible if a certain grid comes back with no rows;

However it doesn't work!

I posted the whole button click event for context, but my attempt to my the buttons in/visible is toward the very bottom (some identifying stuff got removed in the code for security reasons).

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void btn_go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string site = this.ddl_site.SelectedValue;
        string srn = this.ddl_al.SelectedValue;

        int siteID = Common.CommonFunctions.XXXXXX_SiteID(site);

        using (DBML.XXXXDataContext db = AuthUtils.Auth.getDataContext(Common.DataContextE.XXXXX, Common.CommonFunctions.getXXXXX_ServerFromString(site)))
        {

            var CHAL = (from gal in db.XXXXXXXAccessLevels
                        where gal.ServerID.Equals((short)siteID)
                        && gal.ServerRecordNumber.ToString().Equals(srn)

                        select gal.XXXXXccessLevels.FirstOrDefault());
            if (CHAL.First() == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("No corresponding CHAL for this GAL [SiteID=" + siteID + ",SRN=" + srn + "]");
            }

            BaseClasses.XXXXXXX_AccessLevel al = new BaseClasses.XXXXXXX_AccessLevel(CHAL.FirstOrDefault());

            this.lbl_al_tag.Text = "Access Level Name: ";
            this.lbl_al_name.Text = al.AccessLevelName;
            this.lbl_al_desc_tag.Text = "Access Level Descr: ";
            this.lbl_al_desc.Text = al.AccessLevelDesc;

            this.gv_people.DataSource = al.getPeople();
            this.gv_people.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gv_people_RowDataBound);

            this.gv_people.DataBind();

            this.gv_doors.DataSource = al.getDoors();

            this.gv_doors.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gv_doors_RowDataBound);

            this.gv_doors.DataBind();

            this.gv_doors.Visible = true;
            this.gv_people.Visible = true;
            this.lbl_al_name.Visible = true;
            this.lbl_al_desc.Visible = true;

            //attempt to hide export buttons for 
            ////Working on this right here
            int rowCount = this.gv_doors.Rows.Count;
            if (rowCount > 0)
            {
                export_excel.Visible = true;
                export_excell_both.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                export_excel.Visible = false;
                export_excell_both.Visible = false;

            }




        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure `this.gv_doors` has rows in your tests?

Answer (score 0):

if you try to use `int rowCount = al.getDoors().Count` instead of the rows count of the grid? maybe the grid rows count is not updated yet when you try to access them.